# Tree diagram for Intro to Probability

Tags: probability

Below is a question from John E. Freund's book titled Introduction to Probability. The question is on page 11 and asks you to draw a tree diagram to show that there are altogether 20 ways in which the boy can distribute all, some or none of the candy among himself, his brother, and the friend. The book and question can be found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=tqvDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=tree%20diagram%20introduction%20to%20probability%2020%20ways%20a%20boy%20can%20distribute%20candy&source=bl&ots=W_V6WqQxNn&sig=MxzJen7xgB5yL7ebViKNqCOlpG4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTqfbimJ7dAhXNOcAKHYMPDaYQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=tree%20diagram%20introduction%20to%20probability%2020%20ways%20a%20boy%20can%20distribute%20candy&f=false). However, the tree diagram is illustrated on page 7 shows that there are 10 ways to distribute the candy.

How does one go about showing that there are 20 when there are only 10 ways to distribute the candy. Also, how do I go about inferring the second part of the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example there are 10 ways to distribute *all* of the candy, but the question specifies that he can distribute *all*, *some*, or *none*. Therefore you'll need to have an initial stage in your diagram to show how much of the candy has actually been distributed.

Hint: The first and easiest one to draw is *all* candy distributed, this is just the same as the tree in your example, now consider what could happen if he distributes 2, 1, or 0.

Comment: Thanks MRobinson. I see what you mean.